# How do i change 4 bits using a parameter?

Tags: c

I have a 8bit parameter, I need to send the 4 first digits from this parameter into my PORTC. How do I do this without changing the last 4 bits of PORTC? My first primal thought was to just do parameter=PORTC, but then I change all the 8 bits and not just the 4 first.

Comment: Would you post some code by editing your original post (OP)?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give any information about what PORTC is, which is pretty critical. But for most hardware, you will have to read the entire port first to get its value, change the low 4 bits and write the changed byte back.  Assuming the port is 8 bits wide and by "first fuor digits" you really mean the low 4 bits, the C is:

```
char val = read_port_c();
write_port_c((val & ~0xf) | my_4_bit_value);
```

Comment: @nos As I said, he didn't say what the "first four digits" are.  If he means bits 0-3, then my code is correct. If he means bits4-7, then you are.  OP will have to figure it out.

Comment: @Gene No, nos is right, your description is conflicting with your code. If you want to preserve high bits, then mask must be `0xF0`.

Comment: @nos Thanks. I'm sorry. Left out the `~`.  Typing too fast.

Answer (score 0):

If, by the "first four" you mean the lower four bits, then

```
PORTC = (parameter & 0x0F)
```

What we are doing above is performing a [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operation with the binary value `0000 1111` which means that the upper 4 bits will be cleared and the lower 4 bits will be kept (if 1=>1, if 0=>0). So if your 8 bit parameter is `xxxx yyyy` then after the AND it will be `0000 yyyy`

If you mean the upper four bits, and PORTC needs them in the lower 4

```
PORTC = (paramter >> 4)
```

This means we are [left shifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23.2C_Python) the binary string `xxxx yyyy` down 4 places, so you will get `0000 xxxx` after the shifting operation.

However, sometimes you need to maintain other bits on an output port, so you need to perform a [bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) operation to preserve the existing values.

```
PORTC |= (parameter & 0x0F)
```

or

```
PORTC |= (paramter >> 4)
```

So if we are setting the lower 4 bits, then this assures that we won't change any of the upper bits when we output on the port.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first look in detail at your microprocessor's documentation to see if there is any way for you to read the output state of your IO port.  If there isn't, and reading PORTC just reads the input state of the pins, then you generally need to maintain an "output mirror" - just a copy of your output data.

Then you have to do something like this:

```
static unsigned char outputMirrorC;  /
...
...

// Set the bottom four bits of the port
outputMirrorC &= 0xf0;   // Just keep the top four bits of the mirror
outputMirrorC |= newData & 0x0f;  // Take the bottom four bits from your new data
PORTC = outputMirrorC;   // Write the data to the port
```